# Generate natural language based on similar phrases

Tags: python, nlp, markov-chains

I am working on a project and was hoping the community could share some thoughts on how best to approach it.

Situation:

- In a current business process, people are manually producing similar but slightly distinct descriptions (distinct in terms of syntax, grammar)
- These descriptions are derived from a set of structured data points. More of such data points are being generated continuously
- The objective is to automatically produce descriptions from these data points

The data points are organised as a dictionary in Python, for example:

`thisdict = { "company": "Amazon", "team": "Global Procurement", "employees": 15.0, "contractors": 2.0 }`

Below three examples of typical descriptions that are derived from this dictionary:

- Amazon Global Procurement is supported by 15.0 employees and a team of 2.0 contractors.
- 15 employees are dedicated to Amazon Global Procurement with 2.0 contractors supporting.
- Amazon Global Procurement is supported by 15 heads and an additional 2.0 contractors.

I have a rich data set of these descriptions and the accompanying dictionary with which I hope to train a model that produces descriptions based on new additions to the dictionary.

I thought that the sentence generation task could be approached via Markov Chains. However, I need to preserve the associations in the dictionary (i.e. the number 15.0 needs to be linked to the term 'employees' or related synonyms) and I am not sure how to incorporate these dictionary pairs into the model.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to generate text/sentences given structured data i.e. entities for this particular case. [This](https://github.com/ratishsp/data2text-entity-py) project does the same. You can try out this project.